# What am I doing wrong finding the limit of $\left(\frac{3x^2-x+1}{2x^2+x+1}\right)^\left(\frac{x^3}{1-x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{3x^2-x+1}{2x^2+x+1}\right)^\left(\frac{x^3}{1-x}\right)$$
Divide by $x^2$, get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1,5)^\infty=\infty$$

The answer in the book is $0$.
I've also tried substituting $x$ for $\frac{1}{h}$ where $h$ tends to zero and using some form of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, and using the exponent rule, but everything lands me at infinity.

Do I misunderstand something fundamentally?

Comment: $$(1.5)^{-\infty}=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee ($(\frac{3}{2})^{-\infty}=(\frac{2}{3})^{\infty}=0$, correct?

Comment: @fragileradius Modulo all of that being essentially gibberish, yes.

As far as your question goes, I have no idea what you mean by $(1,5)^\infty$, but it's certainly wrong. 

At any rate, note that $\frac{x^3}{1-x} < 0 for $x > 1$, and go from there.

Comment: @user3482749 here $1, 5$ means $1.5 = 3/2$. Commas are often used interchangably with decimal points. the exponent as $\infty$ is wrong however, and should be $- \infty$ as $x^3/(1-x) = x^2/(x^{-1}-1) \ldots$

Comment: It's not the comma that I'm objecting to. It's the rampant abuse of notation that is using $\infty$ as if it were a real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{3x^2-x+1}{2x^2+x+1} \to \frac32$$

but

$$\frac{x^3}{1-x}=-\frac{x^3}{x-1}\to -\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is the fact that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{1-x}\neq \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Because the natural logarithm is injective, it turns out that: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x²-x+1}{2x²+x+1}^{\frac{x^3}{1-x}}=(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x²-x+1}{2x²+x+1})^{(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^3}{1-x})}$. Thus the limit is $(\frac{3}{2})^{-\infty}=\frac{1}{1.5^{\infty}}=0$.

Comment: We really don't need that argument to justify the limit.